# memory address prints aswell as string?

Tags: c++, memory

I'm trying to print out the contents of my array, however it also prints the memory address of each element, then prints the element.

```
void generateEndOfDayReport(taxiDetails taxiDataStore[], fareDetails reportArray[])
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        {   cout << "Here is a list of the taxi drivers in ascending last name order: " <<
            cout << taxiDataStore[i].taxiDriverSurname << endl << "And here is the money they took in over the course of today: £" <<  taxiDataStore[i].fareDetailsForTaxi.overAllFareDetails << endl << endl;
        }![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Did you somehow overload the <<-operator for the type used for taxiDriverSurname?

Comment: what type is taxiDriverSurename? If it's a custom type, please show us the code so we'll be able to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

By the look of your code, you've got a typo, it reads:

```
cout << some-text << cout << variable << endl << some-more-text << variable << endl << endl;
```

Note that you are streaming `cout` into `cout`. Is that really what you intended?

Comment: Taxi driver surname is just a string value in an array, that's all =)

Comment: @Idov: comment for you, I think?

Comment: @Component10: yep, and you're probably right. He's seeing the address of the "cout" function.